# Save lab price on model to database rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models has_many, through relation : lab, medic_record, and lab_medic. In medic_record model, i have a method to calculate lab price and i have created a migration too for add column "lab_price:decimal" to medic_record

medic_record.rb

```
has_many :lab_medics, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :labs, :through => :lab_medics

before_save :finalize

def lab_price
  Lab.where(:id => self.lab_ids).reduce(0) { |sum, x| sum += x[:price].to_f }
end

private
   def finalize
     self[:lab_price] = lab_price
   end
```

lab.rb

```
has_many :lab_medics, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :medic_records, :through => :lab_medics
```

lab_medic.rb

```
belongs_to :lab
belongs_to :medic_record
```

My question is how to save a lab_price in medic_record model to database 'column :lab_price'? I have tried using 'before_save :finalize' method but the result on database always "0.0" after i created new record for medic_record.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I has changed method with this and its worked !!

```
def self.save_tot(medic)
    medic.update_attributes(lab_price: Lab.where(:id => medic.lab_ids).reduce(0) { |sum, x| sum += x[:price].to_f })
end
```